# Click and Drag component of A-frame for parent entity

Tags: aframe

I have created a dice entity from six plane entities. However, when I click and drag the dice entity, instead of moving that dice, only one sided face gets dragged.
This can be tried hands on at link http://shrouded-chamber-73425.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a box from six planes, you should create one box and use a material that will render the dice faces for you. You can use [three.js CubeTexture](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/textures/CubeTexture):

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('dice-texture', {
  init: function () {
    var box = this.el.getOrCreateObject3D('mesh');

    var loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
    loader.setPath('/images/diceTextures/');
    var textureCube = loader.load([
      '1.png', '2.png',
      '3.png', '4.png',
      '5.png', '6.png'
    ]); 

    box.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({envMap: textureCube);
  }
});

<a-entity geometry="primitive: box" dice-texture></a-entity>
```

Then you can further optimize so that every box shares the same material so you aren't creating a new one each time.

Comment: The textures do not appear. Source code is at https://github.com/prakashsinhab/falling_dices/blob/master/app/views/index.html